# How to search for individuals with duplicate partners

Tags: relationships, duplicate-contacts

We have a data import error where a large number of individuals have two partners, instead of just the one they should have. This causes errors with another system we use that is linked to civicrm. I need to delete the duplicate relationships. Thanks for your help!

Comment: unclear if you mean there are duplicate partners - or duplicate relationships to a single partner. if the former you need to merge Contacts.

Comment: duplicate relationships to a single partner, so a merge does not appear to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to export the Relationship civireport (under Reports - Contact Reports) and then use the power of Excel to analyze it, e.g. pivot on contact_a and relationship-a-b and have it sort by count descending, then anything with 2 or more is a duplicate.

Comment: yep, there doesnt seem to be a way within CiviCRM to tackle this issue, so using excell or something is required

Comment: if you are on Drupal you could build a view, aggregate, would then show all those with multiple relationships. in WP you could try the new Views equivalent. but neither of those will actually delete the relationship, so ideally i think you would be doing this direct in mysql and remove the duplicated relationships in the same task